# iOS - How to locate all files on my IPad/IPhone through Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I am writing an App that will allow users to browse through all files of a certain extension (say PDF, XLS) on my IPhone/IPad. The App will then upload the file to a server.

The App should be able to locate files which are not located in its sandbox directories.

How can this be done in Objective-C?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable users to open documents from other applications into your application and then send them to the server. In the application, you must specify what type of documents you want to open (UTI).

Comment: Hmm..Seems interresting! I will give this a try! Thanks

Comment: It Works!!!..Thanks, this link will give more details to making your App able to be listed in 'Open In' list: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. Your app cannot access files or directories outside of its sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Your app can only access files inside its sandbox directory unless the device is jailbroken. If your app even attempts to read files outside of the sandbox, it will be rejected from the App Store.